# Unknown Issue when trying to add core location

Tags: objective-c, view, crash, core-location, cgaffinetransform

I'm working on an app where I have a subclass of a UIView that contains seven subviews with orientations arranged such that they form a 7-sided shape. Each of these subviews has additional subviews in front of them that are oriented the same way as the main view.

Fine so far. Then I tried adding some code to tap into core location services. I used the basic procedure outlined [at this tutorial.](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42992-how-do-i-make-compass.html) Using the code as it is presented there, I successfully got the heading to display in the debugger window.

Next step was to tie it into my app. To make sure I was on the right track, I simply added this code:

```
   float radianHeading = newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180;
   CGAffineTransform transformTrollCalendar = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radianHeading);
   [self setTransform:transformTrollCalendar];
```

There are two issues. The first is that the view is not visibly rotated. I was prepared for that, because I probably have to trigger something to redraw the view. However, I get another problem that has me worried.

When I get a bunch of updates from the compass, the connection between my mac and my iPad gets lost, as evidenced by the stop button turning grey. Moments later, the iPad makes the sound that you get when you connect the cable to the Mac or power. Then I get the slider that you get when you first power up the iPad. I figure this means I'm doing something majorly wrong. However, the app still appears to be running on the iPad, and it is not generating any crash logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my own problem. Apparently, the problem was the result of my putting the code into the wrong method. I don't remember anymore which wrong method I placed the code into, but when I placed it in the correct method, it worked just fine.

I would have updated this sooner, when it was still fresh on my mind, but I've had a trip to Guatemala in the interim that has caused my memories of this problem to fade.